# Suspicious looking item Google LLC under Allow in Background on Mac OS Ventura

Tags: security

I am using Mac OS Ventura. Just now I got a popup that Google LLC has been added to list of applications running in the background. When I opened the list, I saw this:

[image]

I disabled Google LLC in above. It was enabled when I opened the list. This item looks suspicious to me because of following:

- The logo is not that of Google
- Google is not a LLC

Has anyone seen this and know if this is a legitimate item? I have Chrome installed on my computer but other than that I don't think I have any other Google product installed. thanks.

If this is not a legitimate item what action should I take to fix my computer and get rid of this?

Comment: It's not a logo, it's a "I don't know what it should be" icon. Ventura was famous initially for listing background processes by developer, not process name. I thought they must have fixed it by now. There are previous questions on this - searching……

Comment: BTW, Google **is** an LLC - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google

Comment: @Tetsujin It's not really an issue for Ventura to fix, it's because Developers put their name in fields they weren't expecting to be shown to the public

Comment: thanks. Yes I understand this is probably legit.